# Calculate current and subsequent FY Quarter based on today's date

Tags: vba, excel, date

I am trying to calculate the current FY Quarter (1 October start) based on `=TODAY()` date and the next x number of quarters, with the result being:

```
Q2 2017
Q3 2017
Q4 2017
Q1 2018
...
Qx 20xx
```

With this formula:

```
="Q" & ROUNDDOWN(MOD((TODAY()-DATE(YEAR(TODAY()-365),10,1)+K6*(365/4))/(365/4),4)+1,0)&" "&YEAR(TODAY()+K6*(365/4))
```

The result is:

```
K6=X    Result
0       Q2 2017
1       Q3 2017
2       Q4 2017
3       Q1 2017 * should be 2018
4       Q2 2018
5       Q3 2018
6       Q4 2018
7       Q1 2018 * should be 2019
8       Q2 2019
```

Question 1: the years are changing one quarter before they should, and

Question 2: this is a terrible mess of a formula - is there a way to make it more simple?

Full disclosure, I intend to implement use this formula in a VBA `FOR x = 0...` loop, with x = quarters since today, and setting the cell's formula accordingly.

EDIT: Alternatively, how could the desired output be generated using only VBA, and set in the desired cells as a text string?  A string representing the FY Quarter may make my application more stable.

Comment: When the Q1 starts (October or January - sometimes the FY does not match calendar year). If it's the same as calendar year then why don't you just delete the "+1" in calculation:  `="Q" & ROUNDDOWN(MOD((TODAY()-DATE(YEAR(TODAY()-365),10,1)+K6*(365/4))/(365/4),4),0)&" "&YEAR(TODAY()+K6*(365/4))`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Add this Function to a module sheet

```
Function NextQuarter(ByVal iCQ As Integer) As String
    Dim qtrd As Date
    Dim qtr As Integer

    qtrd = DateAdd("m", 3 + (3 * iCQ), Now())

    qtr = (Month(qtrd ) + 2) \ 3

    NextQuarter = "Q" & qtr & " " & Year(qtrd )

End Function
```

And in your cell use formula "=NextQuarter(K6)"

Comment: Genious! Elegant, and reusable - this is exactly what I need.  My not-working attempt at a VBA function solution isn't much better than the formula which spawned the original post.  In hindsight while exploring the issue, setting the result as a `String` in the appropriate cell is much more appropriate for my intended use.  Awesome!

Answer (score 1):

Try the VBA code below (I put the results in Column A, from row 2):

```
Option Explicit

Sub FormatQandY()

Dim x As Long

For x = 0 To 10 '<-- loop from today 10 Q ahead
    Cells(x + 2, 1) = "Q" & WorksheetFunction.RoundUp((Month(DateAdd("m", x * 3, Date))) / 3, 0) & "-" & Year(DateAdd("m", x * 3, Date))
Next x

End Sub
```