# Find the last date of quarter and show all another day by quarter

Tags: excel, vba, date

I would like to find the last date of quarter using the date on input and show all quarter for 10 years like this :

[image]

My code is :

```
Sub Trimestre()

 If Month(Sheets("Paramétrage").Cells(3, 3).Value) >= 1 And 
 Month(Sheets("Paramétrage").Cells(3, 
 3).Value) <= 3 Then
 Sheets("Paramétrage").Cells(12, 1).Value = "T1"
 End If


 If Month(Sheets("Paramétrage").Cells(3, 3).Value) > 3 And 
Month(Sheets("Paramétrage").Cells(3, 
3).Value) <= 6 Then
Sheets("Paramétrage").Cells(12, 1).Value = "T2"
End If


If Month(Sheets("Paramétrage").Cells(3, 3).Value) > 6 And Month(Sheets("Paramétrage").Cells(3, 
3).Value) <= 9 Then
Sheets("Paramétrage").Cells(12, 1).Value = "T3"

End If


If Month(Sheets("Paramétrage").Cells(3, 3).Value) > 9 And Month(Sheets("Paramétrage").Cells(3, 
3).Value) <= 12 Then
Sheets("Paramétrage").Cells(12, 1).Value = "T4"
End If



End Sub
```

I can find the first T (Quarter) but I have no idea how to find the last date of the quarter and show all the date after. Thank you for your precious help.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41888508/calculate-current-and-subsequent-fy-quarter-based-on-todays-date

Comment: Thank you, I have the quarter, but I don't have the last day of the quarter.

Comment: Are you working with calendar quarters or fiscal quarters?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Loops are not needed. Two one-liners will do for the quarter date calculations:

```vb
DateThisQuarterFirst = DateAdd("q", -1, DateSerial(Year(Date), DatePart("q", Date) * 3 + 1, 1))
 
DateThisQuarterLast = DateAdd("q", 0, DateSerial(Year(Date), DatePart("q", Date) * 3 + 1, 0))
```

Answer (score 0):

This function will always give you the last day of the quarter of whatever date you feed into it.

```
Function LastDayOfQuarter(refDate As Date) As Date
    Dim DT As Date
    DT = WorksheetFunction.EoMonth(refDate, 0)
    Do Until Month(DT) Mod 3 = 0
        DT = Application.WorksheetFunction.EoMonth(DT, 1)
    Loop
    LastDayOfQuarter = DT
End Function
```

And here is the code edited to just return the quarter:

```
Function Quarter(refDate As Date) As String
    Dim DT As Date
    DT = WorksheetFunction.EoMonth(refDate, 0)
    Do Until Month(DT) Mod 3 = 0
        DT = Application.WorksheetFunction.EoMonth(DT, 1)
    Loop
    Quarter = "Q" & Month(DT) / 3
End Function
```

If you star with the function `LastDayOfQuarter in cell B5, then each cell below "=eomonth(B5,3)" then you will get a list of the next number of end dates of quarters.

You can then use the "Quarter" Function to return which quarters those are.

Example:

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: Thank you, Cameron, but I Have only one date (on input). I can't find the last date for Q4, for example, with this function.

Comment: What exactly do you need? You want to input "Q4 2022" and get the return "2022-12-31"?

Comment: I changed my answer to do what you wanted.